# atomic_bool value update, not seen by other processes

Tags: c, struct, c11

I have a program with two processes that communicate with shared memory. On ctrl-c I want both processes to exit. I'm using a `atomic_bool` variable called stop to inform the processes to keep looping or exit when set to true. However when the `atomic_bool` variable stop is set to true the other process does not see the change. Meaning it still prints out 0 instead of 1, but the process that made the change shows 1. So why doesn't the second process see the change from false to true?

Control-c won't work for killing the process so use `killall` instead.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct shared_map
{

    atomic_bool stop;

};

struct shared_map *map;

int compare_and_swap_loop(atomic_bool target, int value)
{
    /* Loop until we can succesfully update the the value. */
    while(1)
    {
        /* Grab a snapshot of the value that need to be updated. */
        bool snapshot = atomic_load(&target);

        if(atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&target, &snapshot, value) == true)
        {
            /* We succesfully updated the value let's exit this loop and return. */
            break;
        }
    }

   printf("result: %d\n", atomic_load(&target));

    return 0;
}

static void ctrlc_handler(int sig)
{
    compare_and_swap_loop(&map->stop, true);

    return;
}

void setup_signal_handler(void)
{
    (void) signal(SIGINT, ctrlc_handler);

    return;
}

static int create_shared(void **pointer, int size)
{
    *pointer = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if(*pointer == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("mmap: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void loop(void)
{
    /* Set up signal handler. */
    setup_signal_handler();

    /* Check if we should stop or continue running. */
    while(atomic_load(&map->stop) == false)
    {
        sleep(2);

        printf("map->stop: %d\n", atomic_load(&map->stop));
    }

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    int rtrn;
    pid_t pid;

    rtrn = create_shared((void **)&map, sizeof(struct shared_map));
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        printf("Can't create shared memory\n");
        return -1;
    }

    atomic_init(&map->stop, false);

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        loop();

        _exit(0);
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        int status;

        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("fork: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing in a copy of your atomic variable to your `compare_and_swap_loop` function, which is not going to do you any good - you need to work on the same value that's shared between your processes.

You need to do it like this:

```
int compare_and_swap_loop(atomic_bool *target, int value)
{
   /* Loop until we can succesfully update the the value. */
   while(1)
   {
    /* Grab a snapshot of the value that need to be updated. */
       bool snapshot = atomic_load(target);

       if(atomic_compare_exchange_weak(target, &snapshot, value) == true)
       {
        /* We succesfully updated the value let's exit this loop and return. */
        break;
       }
   }

   printf("result: %d\n", atomic_load(target));

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code is written without the 'atomic_*' commands
but does show what is incorrect about your process.

Mostly, need to kill the child pid, not the parent pid

The following code displays the child pid, so it is easy to find

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
//#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct shared_map
{
    bool stop;
};

struct shared_map *map;

int compare_and_swap_loop( bool *target )
{
    /* Loop until we can succesfully update the the value. */
    while(1)
    {
        /* Grab a snapshot of the value that need to be updated. */
        bool snapshot = *target;

        if(snapshot)
        {
            /* We succesfully updated the value let's exit this loop and return. */
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static void ctrlc_handler(int sig)
{
    if( SIGINT==sig)
    compare_and_swap_loop(&map->stop);

    return;
}

void setup_signal_handler(void)
{
    (void) signal(SIGINT, ctrlc_handler);

    return;
}

static int create_shared(void **pointer, size_t size)
{
    *pointer = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if(*pointer == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap failed");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void loop(void)
{
    /* Set up signal handler. */
    setup_signal_handler();

    /* Check if we should stop or continue running. */
    while(!map->stop)
    {
        sleep(2);

        printf("map->stop: %d\n", map->stop);
    }

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    int rtrn;
    pid_t pid;

    printf( "entered Main\n");

    rtrn = create_shared((void **)&map, sizeof(struct shared_map));
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        printf("Can't create shared memory\n");
        return -1;
    }

    map->stop = false;

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    { //then child
        printf( "child process\n");
        loop();

        _exit(0);
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    { // then parent
        int status;
        printf( "parent process\n");
        printf( "child Pid: %d\n", pid);

        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

        return 0;
    }
    else
    { // else, fork failed
        perror("fork failed");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```